# Finite Flat Group Schemes are Syntomic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a group scheme which is finite and flat over a base $S$. Then is $G$ always syntomic over $S$, i.e. is $G$ a local complete intersection over $S$?

This reduces immediately to the case where $S = \text{Spec} \ k$, where $k$ is a field (by considering the fibres). Here it is well known to be true for the case where $k$ is perfect. Does it hold in general?

Comment: I believe you can check the LCI property after fppf base change.  So if the result is true for perfect fields, then it is true for every field.

Comment: @JasonStarr: This is Lemma 36.51.12 in the Stacks Project, see here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/068E

Comment: (So the answer seems to be "yes.")

Comment: That indeed solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If one tries to adhere to the principle of giving original references:  EGA IV$_4$, 19.2.4, 19.3.7, 19.3.9(ii). And for the application to such group schemes (finite, flat, and finitely presented over the base), presumably the original paper of Mazur (?) that introduced the word "syntomic" included this argument (sans "Stacks Project" reference!), since I believe exactly this context was the entire motivation for isolating the concept.

Comment: It's worth noting that flat finitely presented group schemes (and not just finite!) are syntomic. Since this is a fibral condition we reduce to the field case and by fpqc locality to the case of an algebraically closed field. Now if $G$ is such a group scheme then $G_{red}$ is smooth over $k$ and so the morphism $G\to G/G_{red}$ is smooth with the target finite. Then use Waterhouse 14.4.

Comment: I learnt this argument from lemma A.2 here https://bogdanzavyalov.com/refs/papers/Lefschetz.pdf